# How does one reuse a thick film circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering

I have a thick film circuit from a calculator that I want to use. How can I attach external connections to the sheet? I tried simply using the circuit as a contact in between a battery positive and an led with the negative attached to see if it would carry signal and it doesn't.

[image: A photograph of the sheet]

Comment: Incidentally, that is much more likely a **thick film** circuit than a thin film circuit. Thick film means essentially printing on the substrate with conductive ink. Thin film means an evaporative or sputtering process where metal is deposited from a gaseous or plasma state.

Comment: @ThePhoton oh ok, thanks for explaining that to me, I thought if it was flexible it was thin and if it was inflexible it was thick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are carbon traces, so can't be soldered to.

Note the fingers at center top.  Those are meant to go into a connector that will mechanically clamp the conductive part against metal contacts in the connector.  They could also be meant for a "zebra stripe" connector, or something that is screwed down on the PCB that holds the carbon against pads on the PCB for that purpose.

Comment: okay, so to use this do I need pressured contact onto the sheet?

Comment: @eric: Like I said, ultimately all the methods come down to clamping the carbon against some other more convenient conducting material.  In some cases a "zebra stripe" intermediate conductor is used, but eventually those signals need to transition to a metal conductor somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but conductive glue (AKA wire glue) *might* enable you to make a connection to wires if you can't obtain a suitable connector.

This probably wouldn't be reliable without some mechanical arrangement to hold the wires with strain relief.

It's also fairly non-reversible.

Comment: This is a good idea too. I broke my zebra stripe connector on accident so I can try to get some of this at least.